# How are the components scanned in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How does spring boot take care of component scan? We do not specify `<component-scan>` tag in spring boot in some web.xml file. We do not write any dispatcher servlet in spring boot. So where does spring boot do a component scan and how does it register all the controllers, services? What is the entry point for the spring boot web services micro-service? Note: Since it is a web-project I may not want to use the main method here.

Comment: When you read the documentation of Spring Boot, which part confused you concerning all these questions?

Comment: If you are running it as a standalone `.jar` then you call [`SpringApplication.run`](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/). If you deploy to a JavaEE container, then Spring Boot has an [`SpringBootServletInitializer`](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications#what-about-the-java-ee-application-server).

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit one for the same package and sub-packages if you take a look at the annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public @interface SpringBootApplication {...
```

Of course, it will be executed after the run method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
```

The question was: we do not specify component-scan and this is not true. It is declared in the Spring Boot annotation.

**Edit 1**: *Spring MVC alternative*

However, `<component-scan>` is a Spring annotation not just Spring Boot. You could configure your WAR web app with Spring MVC and you will not need Spring Boot libraries at all. Take a look at: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-customize

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ConfigWebMVC extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
...
}
```

Additionally, for better understanding of `@ComponentScan` I would like to highlight some points of the documentation:

About bean lifecycle:

> By default, ApplicationContext implementations eagerly create and
>   configure all singleton beans as part of the initialization process..

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lazy-init

About Component scanning:

> By default, classes annotated with @Component, @Repository, @Service,
>   @Controller, or a custom annotation that itself is annotated with
>   @Component are the only detected candidate components. However, you
>   can modify and extend this behavior simply by applying custom filters.
>   Add them as includeFilters or excludeFilters parameters of the
>   @ComponentScan annotation (or as include-filter or exclude-filter
>   sub-elements of the component-scan element)

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-filters

Comment: You still need to call `SpringApplication.run` - that bootstraps the entire process...

Comment: I know that `@SpringBootApplication` includes `@ComponentScan`. But this is written on the top of main method. I want  to run my application using jar file. Basically i want to get rid of main method to trigger my application and still get my components scanned.

Comment: Now I understand. You don't need Spring Boot, you only need spring mvc. Configures your Web adapter, creates a war file to be deployed on a servlet container and has the the components can behaviour.